In a world with magic that can be used to create fireballs cast from a persons hands, could setting off a fireball underwater create temporary oxygen?
My character in my story can wield magic, and this includes creating fireballs she can shoot from her hands. In one chapter, she falls into the ocean and is struggling to reach the surface again. Would it be possible for her to cast a fireball into the water around her and for it to create some type of brief, oxygen bubble? This is also going off the assumption that she cannot be hurt by her own created fire, and that the fire would be strong enough/magically infused enough to not be immediately extinguished upon contact with the water (unless that would be required for the oxygen to be created??) IDK this may be a dumb question but I am very curious. Thank you!!

Several answers ask for more info on how exactly your mage creates fireball. Is it just heat and light created in an expanding sphere? Or is it summoning oxygen and hydrogen in relative quantities and triggering a regular physics thermal reaction?

You could also use the fire to reach the surface faster.

Maybe, but that’s not how breathing works. A sudden underwater oxygen explosion is not what our lungs are designed for, on multiple accounts.

It's magic,  so anything is possible.

don't forget the humans need to breathe a mixture of gases To breathe pure oxygen for extended periods can have toxic results, including "shock lung," or adult respiratory distress syndrome

@SRM, Re, "summoning oxygen and hydrogen in relative quantities..." Although igniting a stoichiometric mix of H2 gas and O2 gas in the face of your enemy might be a useful combat tactic, I think most people would choose a different word than "fireball" to describe the experience. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMB2VR0087w&t=16s (While you're there, read the comments that talk about how loud it was.)

That is the very reason why one doesn't use water to extinguish very hot fires: water thermal decomposition. It results in water breaking down into oxygen and hydrogen, which then want to combine back releasing energy.

In thermolysis, water molecules split into hydrogen and oxygen. For example, at 2,200 °C (2,470 K; 3,990 °F) about three percent of all H2O are dissociated into various combinations of hydrogen and oxygen atoms, mostly H, H2, O, O2, and OH. Other reaction products like H2O2 or HO2 remain minor. At the very high temperature of 3,000 °C (3,270 K; 5,430 °F) more than half of the water molecules are decomposed.

If your characters can create such a hot flame, they will surely be able to create oxygen underwater. How they manage to avoid the related explosion once it combines back with hydrogen, though, it's an exercise I leave to the reader.

Water expands by about 1600 times when evaporated, thus: the explosion. Even if the fire and explosion don't hurt, the shock wave is going to compress your lungs, and cost you more air than you just created (and your ribs). Even if you can ignore all side-effects, you just pulled a mantis shrimp punch on a VERY LARGE scale. The supercavitation when the water collapses into the space it just occupied again is going to create another shock wave, one strong enough to kill you all over again.

Won't the recombination of any thermolysis products at best release the same amount of energy it took to split the water in the first place? If the mage can survive the their initial fireball, they can survive a smaller one. I think the steam explosion is the bigger issue as @vinzzz001 suggests.

What this really means, and it's important!, is that in Kass' world Kass can do what she wants to do so long as the fireballs are hot, hot, hot! Whether or not Kass wants to incorporate the aftereffects of Real Life is up to Kass, and thank goodness! Because the aftereffects of actual science take all the fun out of most worldbuilding, especially fantasy worldbuilding. +1

@JBH: True, but the more detailed “hard science” a creator invokes, the harder it is to wave away inconvenient after-effects while maintaining verisimilitude.  It’s one thing to say “as the water boiled around her hands, she gasped a few much-needed mouthfuls or air from the rising bubbles” — but saying “The thermolysis from her ultra-hot flame split the water around her to its component molecules, releasing vital oxygen…” invites more careful thought about the consequences than the idea quite stands up to.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine This stack has constantly fought becomeing physics-lite. The OP did NOT tag this question [tag:hard-science] or [tag:science-based]. In fact, quite contradictory to your comment, it's tagged ['tag:balancing-magic-systems]. I believe the OP came up with an excellent rationalization for a worldbuilding rule in her imaginary world. (And I'd be more than a little suprised if the OP used the word "thermolysis.")

@JBH: Absolutely!  I just wanted to caution about mixing-and-matching between different levels of science hardness in worldbuilding.  Your comment gives excellent advice about when to disregard inconvenient science, and this answer gives a good piece of relevant hard science — both excellent, but combining them needs to be done rather judiciously.

Reverse the spell.
On the basis that every spell has its opposite, a spell to create fire's opposite would be one that "un-burns" something.
Water is hydrogen that's been burned in air (simply), so what your caster wants to do is un-burn the hydrogen gas.
I figure that this will have the opposite effect of fire, in that it will drop the temperature, possibly causing ice to form as it's cast. It'll make hydrogen gas and oxygen gas - neat.  The other effect it'll have is that just like breathing in helium, it'll make the voice squeaky.
Another effect will be the relatively large proportion of oxygen, might make a person dizzy - but don't be deceived, we need carbon-dioxide in order to function as well, without it our breathing stops and we die of lack of oxygen (it's a reflex) - so your caster will need to remember to consciously keep breathing in/out or risk passing out and death.

Interested in your last paragraph. Is it really true that you'll stop feeling the need to breathe in a fully oxygen atmosphere? Can you provide a source?

There's no need to inhale carbon dioxide for the breathing reflex. You will produce enough carbon dioxide in your lungs for the breathing reflex to operate.

@stickynotememo This is a known problem and a common knowledge in the related fields. This is why medical oxygen contains some percent carbon dioxide. OTOH, a small bubble of gas around the mage is pretty much expected to be enriched by their own exhaled carbon dioxide, so we are overthinking it.

@stickynotememo There you go. It's true, but less dramatic than I made it sound (but it's for your story, up to you if you want a dramatic touch).

If the temperature drops, the hydrogen and oxygen will just recombine back into water. You're describing thermolysis, the splitting of water by using a large amount of input heat energy. That just can't happen at low temperatures - if ice is forming, it's a nearly one-way reaction of turning hydrogen and oxygen gas into water. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/696410/is-water-thermolysis-via-microwave-heating-feasible

@NuclearHoagie Did you mean to leave this comment on another answer?

@Escapeddentalpatient. No - doing something to lower the temperature of the water won't split it into H2 and O2. The opposite of a fire spell that causes water to turn into ice won't result in thermolysis, it just makes ice - your freezer doesn't make H2 and O2 gas. You can't turn water into H2 and O2 by removing energy from it.

Erm, I've not made an argument that lowering the temperature would split water into H2 and O2, I'm arguing that reversing the spell would do that. I'm arguing that a side-effect that's not inconsistent with thermodynamics would be a lowering of temperature. "You can't turn water into H2 and O2 by removing energy from it. "  - I'm not suggesting you can, water is more stable (higher enthalpy) than hydrogen and oxygen. I'm suggesting that  release of energy occurs during water formation  by burning hydrogen, and that (magically) the reverse is true when it's "un-burned" (magically). @NuclearHoag

Heating water does not produce oxygen gas.
If it's important to the story that she has this ability, you could go back to the earliest chapters and explain that she creates fireballs (fuel-air explosions) by conjuring or teleporting small bubbles of fuel and oxygen gas. This would present your character with a new, solvable problem: she needs oxygen, she has a way to get oxygen, but it comes with fuel and spark, which she needs to not have, so that she can get the oxygen before the fire gets it.
On the other hand, if the story works whether she has the ability or not, and you're just checking to make sure there isn't a "Why doesn't she just do X?" you're fine without it. Magic fires are typically their own thing with their own rules in fantasy stories, not a physics consequence of some other kind of magic (like teleporting fuel and oxygen), and you're usually better off that way. You're the boss of the way magic works in your world, so if you find yourself in a situation where "Why doesn't she just do X" is ruining your plot, you can just insert a new rule earlier in the story that prohibits X. But when it comes to physics, your plot has to adapt to reality, instead of you adapting reality to fit your plot.

Heating water produces oxygen, with enough heat. See my answer.

Does it have to be the fireball she uses?
You write that she:

can wield magic, and this includes creating fireballs

"includes", so she can do other magic too, yes? Might there be something lightning-related in her repertoire?
Electrolysis to get oxygen (discard the hydrogen)
Because while the fireball idea seems rather unlikely, we quite commonly use electrolysis to split water into hydrogen and oxygen. And oxygen is what you want.
If you try a home experiment of "connect one wire each to the poles of a battery, place the ends in water (not touching), and put an inverted glass over each" you will get hydrogen collecting in one glass and oxygen in the other, so if her control is good enough she might be able to split the water into hydrogen which collects in one hand, and oxygen in the other (cupped to collect the gas which wants to rise up to the surface as bubbles).
Pure oxygen is bad, recycle breath to get a gas mix
Now I'm no expert, but I believe breathing pure oxygen is not very healthy. It would be best if she could breathe out into some receptacle (does she have a bag? can she summon one? maybe a piece of her clothing could serve - wet cloth can somewhat hold in air...) for the nitrogen (and some carbon dioxide and trace gasses as well as the oxygen her lungs had not filtered out for use). Mix the oxygen she got from electrolysis of the water into that, and she'll have regenerated air - a bit more carbon dioxide than usual, but enough oxygen to live on.
Don't do this long-term, carbon dioxide is bad for you
Note that this might not be feasible long-term - she'll add more and more carbon dioxide to the mix with every time she breathes out. Again, not an expert, but a quick googling of "carbon dioxide poisoning" suggests that high concentrations of this in breathing air is bad for you. But if all she needs is a few more breaths to reach the surface, we can probably handwave this away as "it would only matter if she had to do this for longer".

Acute oxygen toxicity happens around 1.6 atmospheres of partial pressure. For pure oxygen, that's achieved at only 6 metres below the surface. Dangerous! But her electrolysed water will be a 1:2 mix of oxygen with hydrogen, so she'll be fine down to 38m deep (4.8 atmospheres total, 3.2 atmospheres of hydrogen and 1.6 of oxygen) as long as she doesn't mind the squeaky voice and possible risk of blowing herself up. To go deeper she'll need to remove some oxygen from the hydrogen mix. (Deep sea divers call this mix "hydrox".)

@Toph oh, interesting! And here I thought the hydrogen might be dangerous and it would be better to discard it and reuse the nitrogen from the breath she still has in her lungs. Many thanks for this information!

It's still "dangerous" in that a 2:1 mix of hydrogen to oxygen is the optimal ratio for creating an explosion, but presumably a wizard who regularly throws fireballs from her bare hands has some way of dealing with that.

@Toph so she'll have to be REALLY careful with the lightning magic she uses for electrolysis!

From my limited understanding of Science, I'm pretty sure that even if a fireball COULD be created underwater and sustained, any oxygen would be absorbed by the fire. Oxygen is fuel for fire, which is why covering a fire can put it out - you're depriving it of the oxygen. So if you're intending for your character to use fire to create an oxygen source for HER, I don't think it would work. But by all means, defer to a more educated source, if someone has a more informed answer.

[ignoring the thermal decomposition of water]*
That depends where the magic starts and how it works in your world.
Are your flames pure magic? Aka magical light and heat emitted? (because that's what "fire" basically is) Or is the spell summoning combustible material in the perfect arrangement and place desired?
In the first case: nope, no luck.
In the second case: yeah, go ahead. But at that point any skilled mage should be able to just summon oxygen/air on it's own.
*because just as it could give her air to breathe,it could instantly recompose, aka explode as soon as it cools and you're surrounded by water, a well known cooling agent at rather cold temperatures. Also because it's too easy an answer
